# How to extract key/value from maps into separate columns in spark sql

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have table with map in it. I want to make 2 separate columns out of that map - 1. keys column 2. values column.

```
input.show();

+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------+
|addedSkuWithTimestamp|     fbaSKUAdditions|fbaSKURemovals|      merchantId|mfnSKUAdditions|mfnSKURemovals|removedSkuWithTimestamp|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------+
| [Test1 -> 1234567...|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|   A4QA5OYD4Y45F|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|ANOTHER_MERCHANT|             []|          null|                   null|
|                 null|[CLAM_SUNGLASS_CA...|            []|ANOTHER_MERCHANT|             []|          null|                   null|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+--------------+-----------------------+
```

But I want output as

```
test1  123456789 

Test2  123456780
```

How to get 2 different columns (key column and value column) from map?

```
Dataset<Row> removed_skus = input
                    .withColumn("sku", functions.explode(input.col("removedSkuWithTimestamp")))
                    .withColumn("skuType", functions.lit("MFN"))
                    .select(input.col("merchantId").alias("merchant_id"), new Column("sku").,
                            new Column("skuType"))
                    .distinct()
                    .groupBy("merchant_id")
                    .agg(functions.collect_list("sku").alias("removedSkus"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the same input from other answer

```
val df = Seq(
    (Map("timestamp1"->1585008000, "timestamp3"-> 1584921600), "AFN"),
    (Map("timestamp2"-> 1584835200), "AFN"),
    (null, "AFN") 
).toDF("addedSkuWithTimestamp", "skuType")
```

Try using explode, I tested this in spark 2.2.1 and 2.3.1

```
df.select(explode($"addedSkuWithTimestamp")).show(false)
+----------+----------+
|key       |value     |
+----------+----------+
|timestamp1|1585008000|
|timestamp3|1584921600|
|timestamp2|1584835200|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First let's create some data:

```
val df = Seq(
    (Map("sku1"->"timestamp1"), "AFN"),
    (Map("sku2"->"timestamp2"), "AFN"),
    (null, "AFN") 
).toDF("addedSkuWithTimestamp", "skuType")
.show(false)

+---------------------+-------+
|addedSkuWithTimestamp|skuType|
+---------------------+-------+
| [sku1 -> timestamp1]|    AFN|
| [sku2 -> timestamp2]|    AFN|
|                 null|    AFN|
+---------------------+-------+
```

This will have the following schema:

```
scala> df.printSchema()

root
 |-- addedSkuWithTimestamp: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- skuType: string (nullable = true)
```

**Spark < 2.3**

The next code will extract the columns sku_key and sku_value from *addedSkuWithTimestamp* column using the `mapToTupleUDF` udf function:

```
val mapToTupleUDF = udf((sku: Map[String, String]) => if(sku != null) sku.toSeq(0) else null)

df.withColumn("addedSkuWithTimestamp", mapToTupleUDF($"addedSkuWithTimestamp"))
  .withColumn("Sku", when($"addedSkuWithTimestamp".isNotNull, $"addedSkuWithTimestamp._1"))
  .withColumn("Timestamp", when($"addedSkuWithTimestamp".isNotNull, $"addedSkuWithTimestamp._2"))
  .show(false)

+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
|addedSkuWithTimestamp|skuType|Sku |Timestamp |
+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
|[sku1, timestamp1]   |AFN    |sku1|timestamp1|
|[sku2, timestamp2]   |AFN    |sku2|timestamp2|
|null                 |AFN    |null|null      |
+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
```

Note that we can access `addedSkuWithTimestamp._1` only if `addedSkuWithTimestamp` **is not null**.

**Spark >= 2.3**

Since Spark 2.3.0 you can use the build-in `map_values` and `map_keys`:

```
df.withColumn("Sku", map_keys($"addedSkuWithTimestamp").getItem(0))
  .withColumn("Timestamp", map_values($"addedSkuWithTimestamp").getItem(0))
  .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
|addedSkuWithTimestamp|skuType|Sku |Timestamp |
+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
|[sku1 -> timestamp1] |AFN    |sku1|timestamp1|
|[sku2 -> timestamp2] |AFN    |sku2|timestamp2|
|null                 |AFN    |null|null      |
+---------------------+-------+----+----------+
```

Comment: Its bit different. My structure is like this-
scala> input.printSchema();
root
 |-- addedSkuWithTimestamp: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- fbaSKUAdditions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- fbaSKURemovals: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- merchantId: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Got this output-
scala> val trial3 = input.withColumn("sku", $"addedSkuWithTimestamp.key").withColumn("timestamp", $"addedSkuWithTimestamp.value").select(col("sku"), col("timestamp"));
trial3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sku: bigint, timestamp: bigint]

scala> trial3.show();
+----+---------+
| sku|timestamp|
+----+---------+
|null|     null|
|null|     null|
|null|     null|

Comment: Hi @Kavita can you please update your question with this information because is very hard to read it from comments :)?

Comment: Updated answer as well